# Java вывести текст в кавычках

Tags: java, строки

```
window.setText(var.substring(var.indexOf("\""), var.indexOf("\"")));
```

Как мне вывести текст из строки в кавычках, например:

текст текст "кавычки" текст

и вывод: кавычки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для замены всех двойных кавычек на пустую строку можно воспользоваться методом [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
window.setText(var.replaceAll("\"", ""));
```

Вызов:

```
System.out.println("\"Кавычки\"".replaceAll("\"", ""));
```

Вернет:

> Кавычки

Comment: Не нужны тут регулярные выражения, замените `var.replaceAll("\"", "")` на ``var.replace("\"", "")``

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод `indexOf`.

Например

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class Ideone
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            String var = "текст текст \"кавычки\" текст";

            int start = var.indexOf( '\"' ) + 1, end = var.indexOf( '\"', start );

            System.out.println( var.substring( start, end ) );
        }       
    }
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
кавычки
```

Answer (score 0):

Текст в кавычках можно выводить так:

```
System.out.println("'Z'");
```

> 'Z'

То есть, ("тут сами кавычки('')").